# How to not add duplicates to array in O(1) time

Tags: php, arrays, duplicates, time-complexity

I have an INT array. I want to add a number to the array. However, I don't want to add the number if the number already exists. I know I can use `array_unique()` but the time complexity of that is not `O(1)`. How can I do this in `O(1)` time complexity. I know I can make the numbers the keys and have empty values and search use `isset()` to check if the number exists. Is there any other way?

```
$arr = [1,2,3,4];
$arr = add_to_array($arr, 4); // Should not add arr
$arr = add_to_array($arr, 7); // Should add arr

function add_to_array($arr, $num) {
    if(in_array($num, $arr)) {
        $arr[] = $num;
    }
    return $arr;

}
```

Comment: how about using !in_array?

Comment: You could completely reimplement the thing you already said, which is fairly complicated, but in userland where it would be much slower. Or do the thing you said because you've not offered a reason why you can't.

Comment: The thing I said (the thing about `isset()`), is that that the the key pair value, the value is empty, and thats not how you are supposed to use associative arrays

Comment: You could use an associative array with the keys also being the values and use `array_values` if/when necessary to reindex e.g. https://3v4l.org/VZPbB

Comment: _“I know I can make the numbers the keys and have empty values and search use isset() to check if the number exists.”_ - why would you need to _check_ anything? PHP will create `$foo[7]`, when you assign a value to that and it did not already exist, and will overwrite the entry, if it did.

Answer (score -1):

use `in_array()==false` then add to array as below code

```
$arr = [1,2,3,4];
$arr = add_to_array($arr, 4); // Should not add arr
$arr = add_to_array($arr, 7); // Should add arr

function add_to_array($arr, $num) {
   if(in_array($num, $arr) == false) {
       array_push($arr, $num);
    }
    return $arr;
}
```

Your output will be :

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 4 [4] => 7 )
```